# Reduction to LP

Tags: group-theory, linear-programming

What will be the primal and dual of the following problem/
Given an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$, we want to assign non-negative weights to all the edges of $G$, denoted $\{ x_e \mid e\in E \}$ , such that the sum of all the weights is as large as possible, 
subject to the constraint: for each vertex $v\in V$, the sum of the weights of the edges 
incident to $v$ is at most $1$. If we restricted the weights to be non-negative integers, can you 
think what the primal and dual mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Objective Function**: maximise the sum of all weights of the graph $$\max \sum_{e \in E} x_e$$

**Constraint**: For all $v \in V$, sum of weights of edges incident to v is at most 1. $$\sum_{w \in V} x_{vw} \leq 1 \quad \forall v \in V$$

If you restrict the weights to simply be non-negative integers, that basically means $x_e = 0$ or $x_e = 1$ for all $e \in E$ due to the constraint. For this type of problem, I suggest looking up the concept of 'matchings' in a graph for a general idea of what the formulation solves.

For the dual, I suggest figuring out the formulation with actual examples. Hopefully that'll help you figure out what the dual solves for.